# ReactJS not reading img tag src

Tags: css, reactjs, react-slick

I have this component

```
     import leftArrow from "../../../../../assets/svg/left.svg";

    export const LeftArrow = (props) => {
  const {className, style, onClick} = props
  return (
    <div
      className="slick-arrow"
      style={{...style, display: 'block'}}
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      <img src={leftArrow} alt="arrow_left"/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm making custom arrows for the react-slick carousel, The problem is images are not being displayed. The path is right but the images are .svg icons.  I'm also using babel. Any solutions, please?

It just displays undefined picture with alt `"arrow left"`

Comment: Can you show how you are importing leftArrow?

Comment: where is leftArrow being imported from?

Comment: Sorry i will update it right now

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to declare the leftArrow path and that is why it is not displaying you the image.

```
 export const LeftArrow = (props) => {
  const leftArrow = 'path_of_img'
  const {className, style, onClick} = props
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      style={{...style, display: 'block'}}
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      <img src={leftArrow} alt="arrow_left"/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Minor adjustments -  You are getting className from props but are not using it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,But it is still not showing

Comment: Try using my syntax. I am not sure if import works like that. Try adding this line const leftArrow = '../../../../../assets/svg/left.svg'

Answer (score 1):

You are using the import wrong way. Try this

```
 export const LeftArrow = (props) => {
  const leftArrow = "../../../../../assets/svg/left.svg";
  const {className, style, onClick} = props;
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      style={{...style, display: 'block'}}
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      <img src={leftArrow} alt="arrow_left"/>
    </div>
  );
}
```